# How can I complete this step in the ArgoUML Class diagram Tour?

Tags: language-agnostic, uml, class-diagram, argouml

I am working through one of the [ArgoUML Tours](http://argouml.tigris.org/tours/index.html) and I am stuck on [Build a Class Diagram: Step #11](http://argouml.tigris.org/tours/bdClassDiagram11.html).

This step asks you to build anonymous realizations between the `Teacher` interface and the `Grad` and `Prof` classes.  I can build *individual* realizations, as shown in **Figure 1**, below; however, I haven't figured out how I can get both `Grad` and `Prof` to show up as they do in Step 11 of the Tour.

Other than the Tour, the ArgoUML documentation is rather sparse; I can't find information on these kind of realizations in [The ArgoUML User Manual](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.32/). Can someone walk me through the steps to make my diagram look like theirs (**Figure 2**)?  I am using the latest stable copy of ArgoUML (Version 0.32.2).

**Figure 1**: My attempt at drawing realizations of `Teacher`
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2**: The class diagram, as shown in the ArgoUML Tours - [Build a Class Diagram: Step #11](http://argouml.tigris.org/tours/bdClassDiagram11.html)
[image: Figure 2]

EDIT:

Originally, I thought `Grad` and `Prof` were multiple realizations of the same interface.  Thanks to Tom Morris for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're just seeing a difference in drawing styles rather than actually a Realization with multiple clients.  If you grab the middle of each realization and put two bends in each to make them zigzag shape and then drag the arrowheads so that they overlay each other (easier if the default click to grid is on), you'll be able to make your diagram look like what's in the picture.

If you think of it, this makes sense since the Class-Interface relationships are really two independent 1:1 relations.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still working through Martin Fowler's UML book, so this detail (difference in drawing styles) was lost on me until you mentioned it.